# render geojson w/ respond_to rails & mapbox/leaflet

Tags: ruby-on-rails, leaflet, mime, mapbox, geojson

So I am currently trying to request some geojson data from my rails controller. I am using the `loadURL` method provided to me through mapbox/leaflet to make the ajax call to my controller.

```
$(document).on("ready", function() {
  L.mapbox.accessToken = 'token is here';
  var userMap = L.mapbox.map('user-map', 'mapbox.run-bike-hike')
    .addControl(L.mapbox.geocoderControl('mapbox.places'))
  .setView([37.7833, -122.4167], 12);
  var featureLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer().loadURL('http://localhost:3000/users/1/trails.geoJson').addTo(userMap)
  console.log(featureLayer);
  // getTrailPoints(userMap);
  featureLayer.on('ready', function(){
    userMap.fitBounds(featureLayer.getBounds());
  });
});
```

The above code is able to hit my controller and my controller is able to retrieve the correct data. Here is what I have in my controller:

```
def index
    user = User.find_by(id: params[:user_id])
    @trails = user.trails
    @geojson = Array.new
    build_geojson(@trails, @geojson)
    p "*" * 50
    p @geojson

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.geojson { render geojson: @geojson }
    end

end
```

The `build_geojson` method works fine, you will have to trust that. However, what is not working is the `format.geojson` and rendering it as geojson. I'm pretty sure I need to create a `Mime` but I am unsure how to do so or in what way I should go about doing it with geojson. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I will also answer any questions.

I do currently have it formatted in just json because geojson is just json. However with mapbox when I do that, I get the following error:

```
http://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/marker/pin-l-tree+00607d.png?access_token=pk.e…hIjoiNDQ5Y2JiODdiZDZmODM0OWI0NmRiNDI5OGQzZWE4ZWIifQ.rVJW4H9TC1cknmRYoZE78w Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)
```

The error basically results in the image not being loaded.

Comment: Geojson is just json, why not just use `format.json` or `format.js` ??

Comment: Updated question @nathanvda

Comment: I do not see how that error is related to the geojson? It is giving an error when loading a marker???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `tree` icon in the currently-supported Mapbox icons. Use `park` instead, which is also a picture of a tree.